# Update mysql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image: number 1]

I have a list of movies here I am trying to change the one with id

[image]

I am trying to change it to this

Below is my code

```
app.put('/movielist/updateMovie',(req,res) =>{
  let update = req.body;
 mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = ?,thumnail_path = ?, description = ?, year_released = ?, language_released = ?  WHERE idmovielist = ?",
 [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,update.idmovielist],
 (err,result) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Try and include errors as text in the body of the question, not as images.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: There is no errors its just that the movie list is not updating I want update all the values that starts with idmovieliest1

Comment: I am trying to change it to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this :

```
app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  var id = req.params.id
  var update = req.body
  mysqlConnection.query('UPDATE movielist SET ? WHERE idmovielist = ?', [update, id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
})
```

In this case you have from your frontend part to pass the id of the movie you want to update and get it in the params.
You could also pass it in the body of your request without adding it to the url

Comment: what if I want to change multiple values and in you code id is undefined

Comment: {
        "idmovielist": 7,
        "name": "Hydrabad Nawabs",
        "thumnail_path": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com.jpg",
        "description": "comedy",
        "year_released": "2006",
        "language_released": "urdu"
    
 }

Comment: [] when I run the thing on post man I get this empty array but my update is not showing